# Prevent video stutter / lag in h264 on iPad

Tags: premiere, ipad

When the iPad stutters playing my video, it continues playing audio at a normal rate. This causes the video to go out of sync until the video can catch up. Is there any setting that triggers a pause instead? Or are there better export settings than what Premiere provides?

I'm exporting video from Adobe Premiere at 4mb / 5mb the application's preset "iPad 2 / iPhone 4s", with the modified resolution of 1024x768 instead of 1200x1080 (or whatever it normally is).

The only way that I know of to resolve this issue is to reduce the mb/s video quality, so I'm hoping someone out there has a better idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the specs page, the current iPad (4) can handle up to 2.5Mbps MPEG 4 video at HD resolution (1920x1080) at 30fps.

Going above this will result in what you described. See discussion link below:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5012754?start=0&tstart=0